# ASP - How to take an already defined XML structure and display it in HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Heres the scenario.   I have a formatted XML structure saved in my database as `nvarchar(max)`.   I need to display this in a webpage.

I can grab the data, but how do I display it?  All the examples I find require an XML file.  I have the datasource.

Answer (score 1):

You can read an XML string with an XML document..

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample {

  public static void Main() {

    // Create the XmlDocument.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");


    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
      using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
      {
        xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Flush();
        string s = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
      }
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx

once you have the xml in an xmlDocument you can toString it and print to the web page

Comment: Okay there is multiple issues with this that i've yet to overcome.  One being there is no aspx structure so you have to place it in a placeholder, then how do you apply the xsl?

Comment: What do you mean there is no aspx structure? can you post the code you have for your page already?

Comment: pure blank standard page, you click new page, all this is behind code, so you have to use a palceholder

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a holder for the data in your ASPX page:

```
<asp:Literal ID="xmlHolder" runat="server" Mode="Encode" />
```

and in your code behind populate it from the database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Fetch the XML from your database
    string xml = "<someTag>Hello</someTag>";

    // Display it on the page
    xmlHolder.Text = xml;
}
```

It's important to set the `Mode="Encode"` property on the Literal to ensure that the value is properly HYML encoded.

Comment: Darin - Mode=Encode matters, thanks!   But still how do you apply an xsl?

Comment: Darin this method just displays the text for example <someTag>Hello</someTag> but i actually want the xml format like this http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog.xsl

Comment: @Mike, so you want to return the XML as `text/xml` response content type? This could be achieved by writing it directly to the response: `Response.Write(xml);` and by setting the proper content type: `Response.ContentType = "text/xml";`.